# EmberJS menu visibility based off of width

Tags: ember.js

So I am trying to figure out a problem that I am having with my menu in mobile vs desktop. So I created a button that can toggle the visibility of the menu, but the behavior of the menu can also change based off the size of the browser window.

While in desktop the menu should be visible
While in mobile the menu should be hidden

Here is a link to some sample code of what I have. If you load it up with the window wide enough, the menu will be displayed. Click the button it hides it, click it again and it shows it.

https://ember-twiddle.com/a907e9e648e6f9fd862cd504fc73b719?openFiles=styles.app.css%2C

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using https://github.com/freshbooks/ember-responsive Its specifically designed to help with that type of problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe checkout [flexi](https://flexi.readme.io).

Generally I think its a good idea to have an service that does monitor the window, and sets a width property accordingly. Next you can have a computed property to toggle if you want to display the menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the menu on desktop regardless of what the button does, the fastest way would be to add this CSS

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .menu {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

You can replace `800px` with whatever width you'd like.

A better way would be to use an add-on or framework, as the other answers have suggested.